# Register more than 1 user using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Does anyone have and idea to register more than 1 user at once with devise?

I have a nested form for users and accounts, because 1 user must have an account, and accounts can have a lot of users, but now i want to just have a button on the register form that says: 'Add another user', and it will append the new fields to the same form for the new user, so when you clicked 'submit', it send a hash with account_attributes nested and also should nest the new user information, kinda bulkified?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the *params* in the controller action, split the *params* into number of users and then loop through each user and use super *paramas*.

Devise creates `registration controller` with `create` action.

you can tweak here to get the desired.

`def create
      # params = {"users"=>{"test1"=>{:name=>"test1", :age=>20}, "test2"=>{:name=>"test2", :age=>22}}}
      params["users"].each do |each_user|
        super each_user
      end
  end`

Comment: But how do i nested in the form? i already have a nested account in the form, something like `fields_for :account` but how do i achieve the same with the user?